# Remote restart server by ipmitool

Tags: ipmi, ipmitool

I can't restart remote server with ipmi.

I use `ipmitool -U user -P password -H ip -I lan chassis cycle`, also I tried `power reset` e.t.c, but ipmitools answers `Get HPM.x Capabilities request failed, comcode = d4 Chassis Power Control: Reset` and the server is not restarting. Same problems with power off e.t.c. `ping` is ok.

Comment: I interpret this message as "this user is not allowed to reset the server". To check this, can you access the server's management processor interactively rather than with ipmitool?

Comment: What typebof server are you trying to control HP iLO, Dell iDrac etc. ?